# Database not storing checkbox data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

so I have an input form which contains a few checkboxes, and for some reason my database does not want to store data depending on whether they are pressed.

My code

Index:

```
<table>
    <form action="/htirs" method="POST">
        <tr>
            <td>Rengjort Oppløsningsfilter</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="renOpFilt" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ren Nal</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="renNal" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>kontrSlangTank</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="kontrSlangTank" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>kontrSlangTank</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="kontrSlangTank" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php //Output for om lagringen gikk bra eller ikke.
                if(isset($test3))
                {
                    if($test3)
                    {
                        echo "Lagret i databasen!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Feil! Data ikke lagret!";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<hr/>";
                } ?>
            </td><td><input type="submit" name="lagre3" value="Lagre" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/htirs', 'HomeController@insertHTirs');
```

HomeController:

```
public function insertHTirs()
    {
        $now = new DateTime();
        $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Oslo'));

        $input = Input::all();

        if(Input::get('renOpFilt') == 'on')
        {
            $renOpFilt = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $renOpFilt = 0;
        }

        if(Input::get('renNal') == 'on')
        {
            $renNal = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $renNal = 0;
        }

        if(Input::get('kontrSlangTank') == 'on')
        {
            $kontrSlangTank = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $kontrSlangTank = 0;
        }

        if(Input::get('kontrOgRenPad') == 'on')
        {
            $kontrOgRenPad = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $kontrOgRenPad = 0;
        }


        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $query = DB::table('hvertirsdag')->insert(array(
                'dato' => $now->format('d.m.Y'),
                'tid' => $now->format('H:i'),
                'renOpplFilter' => $renOpFilt,
                'renNal' => $renNal,
                'kontrSlangTank' => $kontrSlangTank,
                'kontrOgRenPad' => $kontrOgRenPad));

            $query2 = DB::table('ansatt_htirs')->insert(array(
                'ansattId' => '1',
                'dato' => $now->format('d.m.Y'),
                'tid' => $now->format('H:i')));
                DB::commit();

                if($query && $query2)
                {
                    $test3 = true;
                    return View::make('index')->with('test3', $test3);
                }

            }
        catch (\PDOException $e)
            {
                DB::rollback();
                $test3 = false;
                return View::make('index')->with('test3', $test3);
            }
    }
```

The only return I get is that it failed to store the data in the database, whereas I can return the variables to the view and echo them out without problems, and I cannot for the life of me figure out where this goes wrong. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes need to have `value` parameter if you want them to send anything. Checkboxes work in a way, that when you check them, their value gets passed in form data. If they are not checked, then they do not send anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's true and I thought as much, but thing is they do return 'on' if they are checked now, I tested it with the value parameter being set to 'on' aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Include checkbox value equivalent to label name . and check with it (isset($_POST[])) store data in db or for further processing